# how do you enable sftp with RCurl package

Tags: r

I am trying to install RCurl package that has sftp support. I install curl with sftp. On console, when I do curl -V, I do get the list of protocols supported:

```
curl 7.39.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.39.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8j zlib/1.2.7 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

However, when I try to install RCurl version RCurl_1.95, I dont see sftp as one of the protocols:

```
 curlVersion()$protocols
 [1] "tftp"   "ftp"    "telnet" "dict"   "ldap"   "ldaps"  "http"   "file"
 [9] "https"  "ftps"
```

Is there a way to force Rcurl include sftp when manually installing the RCurl from the source?

Answer (score 0):

I do not thinks so. While curl/libcurl might provide a huge amount of protocols -- as far as I understand the matter -- **RCurl does not port all theoretically available protocols to be used in R.**

You might either do that yourself or maybe kindly ask Duncan Temple Lang to add further protocols. A **workaround** might be to access curl from within R via `shell()` like this:

```
shell("curl example.com", intern = TRUE)
```